# How versioncode is determined if it is not set in Manifest?

Tags: android

For system apps versioncode is not set in manifest but when I get packageInfo there versionCode in it and it is positive integer. Please tell me how this version code is determined?

Comment: There's also a versionCode and versionNumber in your .gradle file

Comment: *"For system apps versioncode is not set in manifest"* - what makes you say that?

Comment: When you do a `aapt dump badging system-app.apk` on any apk (whether it's installed as system app or not), it *will* have a version code. Without one, updating would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio- version code replaced into build.gradle

Comment: I am not using studio I use eclipse and version code is not set anywhere, is there any relation between api level and version code?